# While trying to integrate the Hyperledger fabric SDK with the Spring boot getting the following error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to integrate the Hyperledger fabric SDK into the Spring boot, while I run the application I am facing the following error,

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.createObjectBuilder(JsonProvider.java:281) ~[javax.json-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
    at javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder(Json.java:327) ~[javax.json-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.NetworkConfig.fromYamlStream(NetworkConfig.java:342) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.8.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.networkConfig(GatewayImpl.java:99) ~[fabric-gateway-java-1.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.networkConfig(GatewayImpl.java:88) ~[fabric-gateway-java-1.4.3.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.networkConfig(GatewayImpl.java:69) ~[fabric-gateway-java-1.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.person.fabricclient.controllers.PersonController.getPerson(PersonController.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Following is the rest controller code,

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/createperson",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPerson() throws IOException {
        Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();

        try {
            // A wallet stores a collection of identities
            Path walletPath = Paths.get("/home/Fabric-samples_1.4/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/identity/user/isabella/wallet");
            Wallet wallet = Wallet.createFileSystemWallet(walletPath);

            String userName = "User1@org1.example.com";

            Path connectionProfile = Paths.get("/home/Fabric-samples_1.4/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/gateway/networkConnection.yaml");

            // Set connection options on the gateway builder
            builder.identity(wallet, userName).networkConfig(connectionProfile).discovery(false);

            // Connect to gateway using application specified parameters
            try(Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {

                // Access PaperNet network
                System.out.println("Use network channel: mychannel.");
                Network network = gateway.getNetwork("mychannel");

                // Get addressability to commercial paper contract
                System.out.println("Use org.papernet.commercialpaper smart contract.");
                Contract contract = network.getContract("person", "org.go.smartcontract");

                // Issue commercial paper
                System.out.println("Submit commercial paper issue transaction.");
                byte[] response = contract.submitTransaction("createCar", "go", "Hello", "2020-05-31");

                // Process response
                System.out.println("Process issue transaction response.");
//                CommercialPaper paper = CommercialPaper.deserialize(response);
//                System.out.println(paper);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ContractException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return "created";
    }
```

When I tried to debug the issue is occurring in the following class, the service loader returns an object when I run in the spring boot, but when I try without spring boot, service loader does not return any object and this line gets executed

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl");
```

in the following class.

```
    //
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package javax.json.spi;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonBuilderFactory;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.json.JsonMergePatch;
import javax.json.JsonNumber;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonPatch;
import javax.json.JsonPatchBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonPointer;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonReaderFactory;
import javax.json.JsonString;
import javax.json.JsonStructure;
import javax.json.JsonValue;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;
import javax.json.JsonWriterFactory;
import javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator;
import javax.json.stream.JsonGeneratorFactory;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParserFactory;

public abstract class JsonProvider {
    private static final String DEFAULT_PROVIDER = "org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl";

    protected JsonProvider() {
    }

    public static JsonProvider provider() {
        ServiceLoader<JsonProvider> loader = ServiceLoader.load(JsonProvider.class);
        Iterator<JsonProvider> it = loader.iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            return (JsonProvider)it.next();
        } else {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl");
                return (JsonProvider)clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException var3) {
                throw new JsonException("Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found", var3);
            } catch (Exception var4) {
                throw new JsonException("Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl could not be instantiated: " + var4, var4);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract JsonParser createParser(Reader var1);

    public abstract JsonParser createParser(InputStream var1);

    public abstract JsonParserFactory createParserFactory(Map<String, ?> var1);

    public abstract JsonGenerator createGenerator(Writer var1);

    public abstract JsonGenerator createGenerator(OutputStream var1);

    public abstract JsonGeneratorFactory createGeneratorFactory(Map<String, ?> var1);

    public abstract JsonReader createReader(Reader var1);

    public abstract JsonReader createReader(InputStream var1);

    public abstract JsonWriter createWriter(Writer var1);

    public abstract JsonWriter createWriter(OutputStream var1);

    public abstract JsonWriterFactory createWriterFactory(Map<String, ?> var1);

    public abstract JsonReaderFactory createReaderFactory(Map<String, ?> var1);

    public abstract JsonObjectBuilder createObjectBuilder();

    public JsonObjectBuilder createObjectBuilder(JsonObject object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonObjectBuilder createObjectBuilder(Map<String, Object> map) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public abstract JsonArrayBuilder createArrayBuilder();

    public JsonArrayBuilder createArrayBuilder(JsonArray array) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonPointer createPointer(String jsonPointer) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonPatchBuilder createPatchBuilder() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonPatchBuilder createPatchBuilder(JsonArray array) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonPatch createPatch(JsonArray array) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonPatch createDiff(JsonStructure source, JsonStructure target) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonMergePatch createMergePatch(JsonValue patch) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonMergePatch createMergeDiff(JsonValue source, JsonValue target) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonArrayBuilder createArrayBuilder(Collection<?> collection) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public abstract JsonBuilderFactory createBuilderFactory(Map<String, ?> var1);

    public JsonString createValue(String value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonNumber createValue(int value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonNumber createValue(long value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonNumber createValue(double value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonNumber createValue(BigDecimal value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public JsonNumber createValue(BigInteger value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues were with the service loader, I had to mention the proper class it should load in the META_INF/Services/ the file should contain the class that should be loaded.

Comment: Hello, I also have the same problem. Could you share your exact solution?

Comment: In the resources folder, create META-INF/services/javax.json.spi.JsonProvider, inside the javax.json.spi.JsonProvider file paste the implementation class of this 'org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl' (without quote). This will select the proper implementation of the Json Provider. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to remove genson from my pom and replace it with com.fasterxml.jackson